# how insert page number to pdf while exporting data from php

Tags: php, codeigniter-url

I am exporting data table from php page to pdf 
I got the page exported to pdf but i can't insert the page number into the pdf file how to insert that
function changeDetails()
    {
        $bType = $this->input->post('textvalue');
if($bType == "pdf")
            {
                $this->load->library('table');
                $this->load->plugin('to_pdf');
                $data['countrytoword'] = $this->AddEditmodel1->export();
                //echo '**CountryList**
';
                $this->table->set_heading('Country','State','Town','Name');
                $out =  $this->table->generate($data['countrytoword']);
                $html = $this->load->view( 'newpdf',$data, true);
                pdf_create($html, $cur_date);
            }
        }
and this is my view page
Name Country State Town

 
    
        
            Name
        
        
            Country
        
        
            State
        
        
            Town

```
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use a library like [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org), it will add page numbers automatically (if you want them that is). Just look at the examples provided.